# average between arrays in Python with nan value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average, nan

I have three arrays in Python

```
a = np.array([[10., 10., 10., 10.], [10., nan, 10., 10.], [10., 10., nan, 10.]])
b = np.array([[10., 10., 10., 10.], [10., 10., 10., nan], [10., 10.,nan, 10]])
c = np.array([[10., nan, 10., 10.], [nan, 10., 10., nan], [10., 10.,nan, 10]])
```

where I need to compute the average to have the following array:

```
>>> myavg 
array([[ 10.,  10,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  nan,  10.]])
```

The first step is convert the arrays in new [0,1] array and sum (i.e. 3 = data in each array, 2=data only in two array, 1=data in olny one array, 0=no data)

```
aa = a.copy()
bb = b.copy()
cc = c.copy()
aa[aa == 10.] = 1
aa[aa != 1] = 0
bb[bb == 10.] = 1
bb[bb != 1] = 0
cc[cc == 10.] = 1
cc[cc != 1] = 0
dd = aa + bb + cc

>>> dd
array([[ 3.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  0.,  3.]])
```

the second is sum all original array and then dived by dd

```
c = a+b+c
>>> c
array([[ 30.,  nan,  30.,  30.],
       [ nan,  nan,  30.,  nan],
       [ 30.,  30.,  nan,  30.]])
```

the problem is quite evident. When I sum a value with nan I got nan. I cannot convert nan to '0' because in my real case 0 is a value (i.e. temperature)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `a`, `b` and `c` into one 3-d array, and then use [`numpy.nanmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html):

```
In [2]: %paste
a = np.array([[10., 10., 10., 10.], [10., nan, 10., 10.], [10., 10., nan, 10.]])
b = np.array([[10., 10., 10., 10.], [10., 10., 10., nan], [10., 10.,nan, 10]])
c = np.array([[10., nan, 10., 10.], [nan, 10., 10., nan], [10., 10.,nan, 10]])

## -- End pasted text --

In [3]: m = np.array([a, b, c])

In [4]: np.nanmean(m, axis=0)
/Users/warren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py:675: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice", RuntimeWarning)
Out[4]: 
array([[ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  nan,  10.]])
```

The warning occurs because in one case, all the values being averaged are nan.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just set the NaN to zero after calculating dd, but before caclulating c. This way the NaN will be ignored in c and you will have the desired average.

An easy way to set NaN to zero is: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

However, there is one more problem, namely your dd matrix has zero at index [2,2]. To fix this, just set that to NaN (since if dd entry is zero, then we can ignore this average / there is no average for this index).

Here is code that works:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

a = np.array([[10., 10., 10., 10.], [10., nan, 10., 10.], [10., 10., nan, 10.]])
b = np.array([[10., 10., 10., 10.], [10., 10., 10., nan], [10., 10.,nan, 10]])
c = np.array([[10., nan, 10., 10.], [nan, 10., 10., nan], [10., 10.,nan, 10]])

aa = a.copy()
bb = b.copy()
cc = c.copy()
aa[aa == 10.] = 1
aa[aa != 1] = 0
bb[bb == 10.] = 1
bb[bb != 1] = 0
cc[cc == 10.] = 1
cc[cc != 1] = 0
dd = aa + bb + cc
dd[dd == 0] = nan

c = np.nan_to_num(a) + np.nan_to_num(b) + np.nan_to_num(c)

your_avg = c / dd

$your_avg
array([[ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
   [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
   [ 10.,  10.,  nan,  10.]])
```

A separate piece of advice. If you can reformat your data to have 12 arrays of three entries each, you can use: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html

Or as Warren suggested, put it into a single 3d array. That's pretty slick!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good use of `masked arrays`.

Combine the 3 into on array (3d):

```
In [257]: abc=np.array([a,b,c])
```

The mean on the 1st axis is what you want - except that `nan` propagates.

```
In [258]: abc.mean(axis=0)
Out[258]: 
array([[ 10.,  nan,  10.,  10.],
       [ nan,  nan,  10.,  nan],
       [ 10.,  10.,  nan,  10.]])
```

Make a masked array, masking out the `nan`:

```
In [259]: abcm=np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(abc),abc)

In [260]: abcm
Out[260]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[[10.0 10.0 10.0 10.0]
  [10.0 -- 10.0 10.0]
  [10.0 10.0 -- 10.0]]

 [[10.0 10.0 10.0 10.0]
  [10.0 10.0 10.0 --]
  [10.0 10.0 -- 10.0]]

 [[10.0 -- 10.0 10.0]
  [-- 10.0 10.0 --]
  [10.0 10.0 -- 10.0]]],
             mask =
 [[[False False False False]
  [False  True False False]
  [False False  True False]]

 [[False False False False]
  [False False False  True]
  [False False  True False]]

 [[False  True False False]
  [ True False False  True]
  [False False  True False]]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Now I can take the mean without the `nan` affecting values - except for the cell where all values are `nan`.

```
In [261]: abcm.mean(axis=0)
Out[261]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[10.0 10.0 10.0 10.0]
 [10.0 10.0 10.0 10.0]
 [10.0 10.0 -- 10.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False  True False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

and back to a regular array with `filled`:

```
In [262]: abcm.mean(axis=0).filled(np.nan)
Out[262]: 
array([[ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  nan,  10.]])
```